Handling unavailable price element with another element
So, I've made this web scraping script for Cypress. It goes to a shop website and scrapes the listed products (product titles and prices). Namely, in the case of certain products, there is no price shown (class name: .sc-dqia0p-3), but instead, there is a message saying that the product is unavailable. In the case of the website I'm testing, the element saying that the product is not available looks like this:
<div 
  data-testid="product-block-unavailable-text" 
  class="sc-bcdv5e-9 hMrYQF"
  >Ovaj proizvod više nije dostupan</div>

Basically, my goal is to set Cypress so that in cases where it cannot find the price element, instead of getting an error for a non-existing element, it should check if there is the other element above and move to the next product after that.
I've tried to solve this by including this else command, which you may see in the code below, but for some reason, Cypress still gets stuck at the part where it says that the price element is missing without even checking for the other element.
// Scrape the loaded products
                    cy.get('.sc-y4jrw3-7').each((productName, index, list) => {
                        // Check if the product is unavailable
                        cy.get('.sc-dqia0p-3').eq(index).then((priceElement) => {
                            // Check if the price element is available
                            if (Cypress.$(priceElement).length > 0) {
                                const title = productName.text().trim();
                                let price = priceElement.text().trim();

                                // Append "din" to the price
                                price = `${price} din`;

                                // Store product data in the products array
                                products.push({ title, price });
                            } else {
                                // Check if the product is unavailable
                                cy.get('.sc-bcdv5e-9').eq(index).then((unavailableElement) => {
                                    const unavailableText = unavailableElement.text().trim();
                                    if (unavailableText === 'Ovaj proizvod više nije dostupan') {
                                        cy.log(`Product ${index + 1} is unavailable. Skipping...`);
                                    } else {
                                        cy.log(`Product element at index ${index} not found or unavailable. Skipping...`);
                                    }
                                });
                            }



sorry i can't give a long explanation until later however .find() should make it work. personally i just use cy.get('body').then(($body) => {if ($body.find('myElement').length > 0){code}}else{code}). Hope this helps you real quick, if not i will be writing a more in depth answer when i have time. Not too sure if .eq() works on this though.

Why would you use $body? The goal is to find the price within product, so you should use $product instead.

If some products don't have a price, getting price like this cy.get('.sc-dqia0p-3').eq(index) will be out of sync with the product list if an earlier product was missing a price element.
An example in pseudo-code:
<product><price></price></product>   // product index=0, price index=0
<product></product>                  // product index=1, price index does not exist
<product><price></price></product>   // product index=2, price index=1

You want to drop cy.get('.sc-dqia0p-3').eq(index) and use product.find(price) which is the jQuery .find() method (note, it's different to the Cypress .find() method).
const productSelector = '.sc-y4jrw3-7'
const priceSelector = '.sc-dqia0p-3'

cy.get(productSelector).each($product => {

  // jQuery find() won't fail the test
  const $price = $product.find(priceSelector)   

  if($price.length > 0) {

  } else {

  }

})


Right I understand it now! So basically this way we are not looking for the price element inside of each product, but we are looking for price element everywhere where it is given :)

We are still looking at every product because of cy.get(productSelector).each() then for each one we find out if it has a price with const $price = $product.find(priceSelector). The result $price is a jQuery object that has length property, which can tell us if the price exists for that product.

It will work ok if you are just screen scraping data and not clicking anything on the product - such as "add to cart", for example.
